# Standard for RESful service with differing models?

Tags: rest, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

From the perspective of an MVC developer, the Model should only contain Properties relevant to the view. So what is the best practice for dealing with this RESTful service scenario?

**Usage 1**

The RESTful endpoint `"my-application/items/"` is used to `QUERY` for a list of items which are bound to a paged list view of the items. It may contain many properties, such as `ItemId`, `ItemName`, `CreatedDate`, `ModifiedDate`, etc. It may even be a paged result of data from the server (eg 10 records out of 1000).

**Usage 2**

In a different area of the application, I need a select box for these `items`. In this scenario, I just need `ItemId` and `ItemName`. All other properties are irrelevant.

**Do I...**

- ...swallow my MVC pride and just use a single bloated model and a
  single RESTful endpoint?
- ...create different RESTful endpoints with some sort of naming standard?
- ...do something else?

Comment: Might depend on one's personal choice; I would use app/items for sending the paged items list and app/lookup/items for filling dropdown values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this is not a theoretical REST issue. This is an implementation issue. Basically, you are asking whether you should implement a different endpoint for a separate use case or not. I agree with you when you say that the information exchanged with the client should be the minimum for performing a specific task. The only reason not to do so is convenience or budget.

In the use case 1, you should provide a wide set of data, in use case 2 you need far less of them..

Maybe use an endpoint as such `.../items/details` for the use case 1 and another endpoint `.../items` for the use case 2.

Maybe you could also implement a single endpoint and use a query parameter as such

```
.../items?detailed=true
```

Both solutions are perfectly acceptable.

The theoretical explanation behind this consideration is that REST asks the server to exchange resources' representation with the client. *Representation* means something similar to the view concept of the MVC model: it's not the entity itself, it's the *most convenient way of describing it in a given context*.

And this also means that different contexts may require different representations.

Comment: Nice detailed explanation. I was worried the having multiple endpoints seemingly returning the same model was against some rule or standard. I quite like the comment from @Developer as a solution as there are many areas with the same usecase. Would endpoints such as `...\lookups\items` and `...\lookups\other-items` be acceptable? This way I can have a "lookups" service for handing them out as opposed to the detailed models.

Comment: As regards your comment above let me point out that not only it is perfectly acceptable to have multiple endpoints managing the same entity and providing different representations, it is also fine to have multiple endpoints exposing the sape representation of an entity. They are called *aliases*.